# Error on finding file and on the New File location

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class running{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    double sum=0.0;
    double num=0.0;

    FileReader fin = (new File("running.txt");
    Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);

    while (src.hasNext()){
      if(src.hasNextDouble()){
        num=src.nextDouble();
        sum=sum+num;
        System.out.println(sum);
      }else{
        break;
      }
    }
    fin.close();
  }
}
```

Around the Scanner portion I cant seem to fix the error.
It says File cant be resolved to a type.
And the file cant be found.

Comment: `FileReader fin = new FileReader(new File("running.txt"));`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `import java.io.File;` statement. Since you did not import this class (and since your code is not located in the `java.io` package), Java can't recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a type in your code. You code should be:

```
FileReader fin = new FileReader(new File("running.txt"));
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can't store instance of File within FileReader.

Also the error that you see is because you have not imported `java.io.File`, so you need to import File like:

```
import java.io.File;
```

A side note: You will need to handle FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing java.io.File, and change your FileReader line to the following:

```
FileReader fin = new FileReader(new File("running.txt"));
```

It compiled fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class running{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
double sum=0.0;
double num=0.0;

FileReader fin = (new File("running.txt");
Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);
try{
while (src.hasNext()){
  if(src.hasNextDouble()){
    num=src.nextDouble();
    sum=sum+num;
    System.out.println(sum);
  }else{
    break;
  }
}
}catch(Exception e){}finally{fin.close();}
}
}
```